# How can I prevent a div from becoming a link?

Tags: html, css

Please check my code, click "Run" to see the [result](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNVDN6NQAW7V).

I want that the picture will be centered, and will used as a link, but the problem is that the whole div is becoming a link and I don't want that. As you can see the div itself is a link, even outside the picture borders. How can I make sure that ONLY the image is a link, and not the area around it?

My code:

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myImage {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

(I'm looking for a simple solution that will work in all main browsers)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have applied `display:block` in the `<img>` so it will take whole width.

Use `text-align:center` to align image in center and remove `display:block` from image

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0; /*for removing the below space in inline elements */
}

.myImage {
  width: 270px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

or you can use **Flexbox**

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.myImage {
  width: 270px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The text-align:center works great! But I don't understand, if it's also centering images, then why did they called it "text-align" ? It's very confusing.

Comment: @JohnAdams `text-align` is used to align the inline elements...and the `img` is a inline element by default

Comment: But it's still confusing because the name "text-align" suggest that it's only aligning text.

Comment: @JohnAdams This is defined in the documentation....Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align...BTW text-align suggest that it will align elements like text(i.e inline) not only text...